# How to center nav using CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, css, nav

I am looking for help to center my navigation bar on my website [Meridian Ridge](http://www.meridianridgect.com/) 
I've looked at quite a few of these questions that asked this already and tried what they were saying such as using display:inline & margin: 0 auto but nothing I do seems to work

Comment: As  well pointed by @Isabel Inc, margin auto requires a fixed width. I prefer using flex because you can have a percentile width.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to a site or an example**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: @Manatax thank you for explaining that I needed to have a fixed with to use margin auto!

Comment: Not a problem. For future reference, if you plan to keep using stackexchange, I would head @Paulie_D's advice and read the rules. The idea is that your question will be someone else's question some day, and we want our answers to help them as well, but that wont happen if they can't compare your problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#header-right-section {
    text-align: center;
}

.main-navigation {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#menu-meridian-ridge{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 700px;
}
```

You need to specify a width that is not auto for margin 0 auto to work

Answer (score 1):

Or you can also use this:

```
#menu-meridian-ridge {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: I like this @Manatax. It's easy and simple. Only issue is if you care about ie support.

Comment: IE 11 has some support, none the less IE is finally fading away with Microsoft pushing windows 10 with edge ;) the days of IE support are happily coming to an end.

Comment: Yes I couldn't agree more. But there are still plenty of people out there who use old versions of IE. Hopefully all will be standard soon :)

Comment: I have made it a part of my job to not support older versions of IE and  to force users to upgrade their browsers. I literally detect the browsers and redirect them to an "update your browser page" ^_^

Comment: Haha. We need more people like you. I generally use browsehappy for outdated users.

Answer (score 1):

The CodePen linked below was an answer to another navigation-related question, but it uses `display:inline-block` to achieve a center-aligned navigation structure and should provide you a foundation for learning how to best achieve this style.

http://codepen.io/rkieru/pen/JKyYpx

```
.navbar {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 4px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar li { 
    display: inline-block; 
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.navbar a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever element you use for your navigation just determine how wide you want it to be.

```
div.navigation {
   width:992px;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
}
```